# Resize tab contents in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am completely new to JavaFX, well any UI development in Java if I am honest. I am using fxml to define my screen layout.

I want an application that uses tabs, witht he first tab having an internal layout rather similar to the IssueTracker sample application. I have created the below fxml file which looks about right, however when I resize the application the tabs and their contents do not resize with the screen.

How do I make this resize? Do I need to do it within code or can I do it within the fxml?

Thanks

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Color?>
<VBox id="vbox" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1000.0" styleClass="root" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="XXXXXX">
  <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar">
    <menus>
      <Menu text="File">
        <items>
          <MenuItem onAction="#handleExitMenuItem" text="Exit" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
      <Menu text="Help">
        <items>
          <MenuItem text="About" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
    </menus>
  </MenuBar>
  <TabPane prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="950.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
    <tabs>
      <Tab text="AAAA">
        <content>
            <AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="600" prefWidth="900.0">
              <children>
                <SplitPane id="Split Pane (Vertical Splits)" dividerPositions="0.23661270236612703" focusTraversable="true" minHeight="550.0" minWidth="800.0" prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="800.0" styleClass="vsplitpane" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
                  <items>
                    <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="100.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" styleClass="vSplitPaneLeft">
                      <children>
                        <ListView fx:id="list" prefHeight="553.0" prefWidth="187.0" styleClass="blackList" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                      </children>
                    </AnchorPane>
                    <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                      <children>
                        <SplitPane id="Split Pane (Horizontal Splits)" dividerPositions="0.3381294964028777" focusTraversable="true" minHeight="598.0" minWidth="400.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="598.0" prefWidth="607.0" styleClass="hsplitpane" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                          <items>
                            <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
                              <children>
                                <TableView fx:id="table" minHeight="182.0" minWidth="596.0" prefHeight="182.0" prefWidth="596.0" styleClass="bugsTable" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-1.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="1.0">
                                  <columns>
                                    <TableColumn maxWidth="500.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="Name" fx:id="colName" />
                                    <TableColumn maxWidth="1300.0" minWidth="130.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Date" fx:id="colDate" />
                                    <TableColumn maxWidth="700.0" minWidth="70.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Priority" fx:id="colPriority" />
                                    <TableColumn maxWidth="500.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="Status" fx:id="colStatus" />
                                    <TableColumn maxWidth="2500.0" minWidth="250.0" prefWidth="250.0" text="Synopsis" fx:id="colSynopsis" />
                                  </columns>
                                </TableView>
                              </children>
                            </AnchorPane>
                            <AnchorPane fx:id="details" minHeight="360.0" minWidth="350.0" prefHeight="360.0" prefWidth="350.0">
                              <children>
                                <AnchorPane id="activityArea" minHeight="49.99987793" minWidth="573.0" prefHeight="49.99997793" prefWidth="573.0" styleClass="roundedAnchorPane" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="19.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0">
                                  <children>
                                    <Label id="activityLabel" styleClass="propLabel" text="ACTIVITY" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="11.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="4.0" />
                                    <TextField fx:id="activityField" editable="false" layoutY="18.0" styleClass="descriptionValue" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="17.6" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="22.6" />
                                  </children>
                                </AnchorPane>
                                <AnchorPane id="descriptionArea" minHeight="146.0" minWidth="385.0" prefHeight="158.0" prefWidth="392.0" styleClass="roundedAnchorPane" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="82.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="201.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="121.0">
                                  <children>
                                    <Label id="descriptionLabel" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="8.0" styleClass="propLabel" text="DESCRIPTION" />
                                    <TextArea fx:id="descriptionValue" minHeight="118.0" minWidth="374.19" prefHeight="127.0" prefWidth="374.19" styleClass="descriptionValue" text="TextArea" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="11.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="12.81" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0" />
                                  </children>
                                </AnchorPane>
                                <AnchorPane id="propertyArea" minHeight="158.0" minWidth="156.0" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="160.0" styleClass="roundedAnchorPane" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="121.0">
                                  <children>
                                    <TextField fx:id="creationTimeValue" editable="false" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="128.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="142.0" styleClass="propTextField" text="Creation time" />
                                    <Label id="creationTimeLabel" contentDisplay="TOP" layoutY="111.0" styleClass="propLabel" text="CREATED" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="11.0" />
                                    <Line id="Line" endX="60.0" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="101.0" startX="-100.0" styleClass="dividerLines">
                                      <stroke>
                                        <Color blue="0.400" green="0.400" red="0.400" fx:id="x1" />
                                      </stroke>
                                    </Line>
                                    <TextField fx:id="statusValue" editable="false" layoutY="76.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="142.0" styleClass="propTextField" text="Status" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="12.0" />
                                    <Label id="statusLabel" layoutY="62.0" styleClass="propLabel" text="STATUS" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="11.0" />
                                    <Line id="Line" endX="60.0" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="51.0" startX="-100.0" stroke="$x1" styleClass="dividerLines" />
                                    <TextField fx:id="priorityValue" editable="false" layoutY="26.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="142.0" styleClass="propTextField" text="Priority" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="12.0" />
                                    <Label id="priorityLabel" layoutY="12.0" styleClass="propLabel" text="PRIORITY" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="11.0" />
                                  </children>
                                </AnchorPane>
                                <TextField fx:id="synopsis" minWidth="573.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="573.0" styleClass="synopsisField" text="Synopsis" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="19.5" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.5" AnchorPane.topAnchor="77.0" />
                                <AnchorPane fx:id="titleLine" layoutY="13.0" minHeight="57.0" minWidth="573.0" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="573.0" styleClass="roundedAnchorPane" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0">
                                  <children>
                                    <Label id="Label" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="9.0" styleClass="propLabel" text="PROJECT / ID" />
                                    <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="27.0" spacing="5.0">
                                      <children>
                                        <Label id="Label" fx:id="displayedIssueLabel" text="Project / Bug ID" />
                                      </children>
                                    </HBox>
                                  </children>
                                </AnchorPane>
                              </children>
                            </AnchorPane>
                          </items>
                        </SplitPane>
                      </children>
                    </AnchorPane>
                  </items>
                </SplitPane>
                <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" minHeight="46.000099999997474" minWidth="400.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="800.0" styleClass="topBarBackground" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                  <children>
                    <GridPane id="GridPane" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="773.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="13.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="11.0">
                      <children>
                        <ImageView id="IssueTracking" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
                          <image>
                            <!--<Image url="@IssueTracking.png" preserveRatio="true" smooth="true" />-->
                          </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <Label fx:id="messageBar" maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="269.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
                        <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" fillHeight="false" spacing="15.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
                          <children>
                            <Button fx:id="newIssue" alignment="CENTER" minWidth="62.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="66.0" styleClass="roundedButton" text="New" textOverrun="CLIP" />
                            <Button fx:id="saveIssue" alignment="CENTER" minWidth="62.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="66.0" styleClass="roundedButton" text="Save" />
                            <Button fx:id="deleteIssue" alignment="CENTER" minWidth="62.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="66.0" styleClass="roundedButton" text="Delete" />
                          </children>
                        </HBox>
                      </children>
                      <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="10.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="10.0" />
                      </columnConstraints>
                      <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      </rowConstraints>
                    </GridPane>
                  </children>
                </AnchorPane>
              </children>
              <stylesheets>
                <URL value="@Login.css" />
              </stylesheets>
            </AnchorPane>
        </content>
      </Tab>
      <Tab text="BBBB">
        <content>
          <AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
        </content>
      </Tab>
    </tabs>
  </TabPane>
</VBox>
```

Comment: It is being resized. Exactly which component doesn't resize?

Comment: The tab contents do not expand so I get a large blank area at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: in the first line after all imports, replace prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1000.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="10.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javafx components automatically adjust themselves according to the size available to them. Try removing the prefHeight and prefWidth, as it forces the components to use a particular dimension.

Answer (score 0):

The blank space at the bottom of the screen could be because of placing everything under VBox.
If i understand it right, you need to have a menubar on the top and Tabpane at the center of the screen. If thats the case, instead of VBox, try using Borderpane with Menubar added to Top and TabPane added to the center of BorderPane.