# Load FXML into AnchorPane destroys Layout?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to load an FXML into an existing AnchorPane using:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane content;

...

AnchorPane newPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/scene2.fxml"));
this.content.getChildren().setAll(newPane);
```

And all that works well, but it destroys the layout of scene2.fxml, as it shows itself in prefered size. I would like to have it dynamically adapted though to the size of the parent FXML (basically have the size that the AnchorPane of scene1.fxml has).

What is wrong in my code? Where is the bug? How do I adapt the size of scene2.fxml automatically?

Comment: If I am not missing something, Your question should be `How do I adapt the size of scene1.fxml automatically?`

Comment: Yes, those could be other words the same issue fits into. Right now scene2.fxml looks quite alien like some non-resizable "picture" inside of scene1.fxml. I'd like to change that to automatic adaption.

Comment: Please refer my answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see to it that you may have specified `prefSize` to the `AnchorPane` in `scene2.fxml`. Children will only adapt to parent if there is no prefSize() assigned to them.

Have a look at

[Resize tab contents in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893300/resize-tab-contents-in-javafx/21905903#21905903)

Comment: I checked your link, though I couldn't find the problem in my code with it.
Therefore I created a new clean post refering to this issue a bit more properly in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066555/how-to-resize-automatically-when-loading-an-fxml-into-an-anchorpane